# Problem compiling React-Bootstrap in SPFx Project

Tags: spfx, error, react, boot-strap

I have installed react-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6 on my machine and included it in my project with `'import ~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'`.

When I run gulp serve I get the following error:

```
[13:46:14] Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./lib/webparts/mslHomePage/components/MslHomePage.module.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./lib/webparts/mslHomePage/components/MslHomePage.module.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError
(40:4) Missed semicolon
 @ ./lib/webparts/mslHomePage/components/MslHomePage.module.css 1:14-161
 @ ./lib/webparts/mslHomePage/components/MslHomePage.module.scss.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/mslHomePage/components/MslHomePage.js
 @ ./lib/webparts/mslHomePage/MslHomePageWebPart.js
```

This doesn't happen if I don't import react-bootstrap.

This is what I have installed:

```
ajv@6.9.1
+-- bootstrap@5.1.0
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- install@0.13.0
+-- npm@7.23.0
+-- office-ui-fabric-react@6.214.0
+-- react@16.14.0
+-- react-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6
+-- react-dom@16.14.0
`-- webpack@4.0.0
```

I'm thinking that there is a problem with the bootstrap CSS that is getting picked up but I can't think what I can do about it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the steps that I did to add bootstrap to my spfx project

```
npm install bootstrap@4 --save
```

In .ts file add the following with correct paths

```
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

In config.json add the following

```
"externals": {
   
     
    "jquery": {
    "path": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "globalName": "jQuery"
    },
    "bootstrap": {
    "path": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "globalName":"bootstrap"
    },
     
      "jqueryui": "node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"
    },
```

Comment: That is compiling ok, how do you reference teh bootstrap classes in your tsx file?

Comment: Sorry, I've worked it out

Comment: Can you please share the solution

Comment: This is how I reference the bootstrap container class in my webpart                              
 <div className="container">